# How to integrate maven with cruise control?

Tags: maven, cruisecontrol

Would like to know how to integarate cruise control with maven?
Cruise Control comes with ant integraation by default and  in the config.xml has antbootstapper.But dint find any bootstrapper for  maven.Would like to know the configuration  for maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to configure maven with cruisecontrol without a need for a specific maven `bootstrapper`.

What you need is a `bootstrapper` for the version control that you are using. Cruisecontrol provides [bootstrappers](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#bootstrappers) for most of them.  Using this, you can update `pom.xml`.

Using the [maven scm plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/usage.html), you can specify the scm configuration in your pom.xml and thereafter run `mvn scm:update` prior to your build. e.g.

```
mvn scm:update clean install
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.do you mean, that i need to configure maven with scm and cc would trigger a build when there is a change in scm?Actually cc is no understanding maven commands and is throwing error.